# How do I find last weeks dates Monday to Friday using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to find last weeks dates

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
Where [Date] Between '04-Jan-2016' AND '15-Jan-2016'
```

Every time I run my SQL Query it needs to display `last week`.

Comment: To get last week first day and last week's last day  - `SELECT DATEADD(wk ,DATEDIFF(wk ,7 ,GETDATE()) ,4) LastWeekFirstDate
      ,DATEADD(wk ,DATEDIFF(wk ,7 ,GETDATE()) ,0) LastWeekLastDate`

Comment: dO YOU WANT COMPLETE DATE LISTING LIKE CALENDAR ? OR ONLY 1ST AND LAST DAY ?

Answer (score 7):

---To get the first day of the previous week in SQL Server, use the following code:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0)
```

--To get the last day of the previous week:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),4)
```

Comment: DATEDIFF only takes two parameters..

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully following is what you want,

```
--START OF LAST WEEK    
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0)

--END OF LAST WEEK    
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 4)

DECLARE @input varchar(10)
--SET @input = '01/10/2016' 
SET @input = GETDATE()

--START OF LAST WEEK    
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, 
CASE DATEPART(dw,@input)
WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(d,-1,@input)
ELSE @input
END
), 0)

--END OF LAST WEEK     
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, 
    CASE DATEPART(dw,@input)
    WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(d,-1,@input)
    ELSE @input
    END
), 4)
```

Comment: `Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 12
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 20
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
`

Comment: Hi @PriceCheaperton you can convert datetime  -->(please check as following url) https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
Where [Date] Between DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0) 
AND DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed the range from the previous Monday at 00:00:00 to the previous Sunday at 23:59:59. This is how you can get that:

```
SET @THIS_MONDAY = SUBDATE(DATE(NOW()), WEEKDAY(NOW()));

SELECT CONCAT(SUBDATE(@THIS_MONDAY, 7), ' 00:00:00') AS last_week_monday,
       CONCAT(SUBDATE(@THIS_MONDAY, 1), ' 23:59:59') AS last_week_sunday;
```

The same without setting a variable:

```
WITH this_week AS (SELECT SUBDATE(DATE(NOW()), WEEKDAY(NOW())) as monday)
SELECT CONCAT(SUBDATE(monday, 7), ' 00:00:00') AS last_week_monday,
       CONCAT(SUBDATE(monday, 1), ' 23:59:59') AS last_week_sunday
FROM this_week;
```

Comment: Just taking the concat out for the time gets me what i needed, and adjusting the SUBDATE parameter for which day I want

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) ,'Last_Sunday'
union all                                                                                        
SELECT DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 2-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) ,'Last_Monday'
union all                                                                                        
SELECT DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 3-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) ,'Last_Tuesday'
union all                                                                                        
SELECT DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 4-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) ,'Last_Wednesday'
union all                                                                                        
SELECT DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 5-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) ,'Last_Thursday'
union all                                                                                        
SELECT DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 6-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) ,'Last_Friday'
union all                                                                                        
SELECT DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) ,'Last_Saturday'
```