# Last week (Monday to Sunday) projects SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I'm making an SQL query that pulls projects that started in the last week, ideally I want to be able to run this any day of the week and get the same result whether to run it tuesday or friday..

I think this works, only problem is that it starts counting back from saturday instead of sunday..

```
HAVING MIN(p.start_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),
INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) + 7) DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),
INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) DAY)
```

Comment: An ideally, would also like to have a YTD version, from January 1st to last sunday

Comment: What about `HAVING MIN(p.start_date) >= DateAdd(w, -1, GET_DATE())`

Comment: I am using MySQL 8.0 with Workbench and SugarCRM

Comment: Have you read this question?
[How do I find last weeks dates Monday to Friday using SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719183/how-do-i-find-last-weeks-dates-monday-to-friday-using-sql-server/34719361)

Comment: Yes, I get problems with the DATEDIFF function, why I have used INTERVAL and made a new thread

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yearweek()`:

```
where yearweek(min(p.startdate)) = yearweek(curdate() - interval 7 day)
```